# How to specify a path to store file in Blackberry JDE?

Tags: blackberry, filesystems, rim-4.6

Dear Friends, Can anyone tell me how to store a file in a blackberry simulator.Actually i m using blackberry jde4.6.I created one simple application in that application i created one edit field and one button if we click the button then the content in the file should store as file i don't how to set a path.If u have any idea how to set path to store data please explain.
regards,
s.kumaran.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the JDE documentation for javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection and javax.microedition.io.file.FileSystemRegistry.listRoots().

Comment: listRoots() shows the mounted file systems. FileConnection (along with Connector.open()) simply allow one to create a file wherever.

The question, though (At least the way I'm reading it) is what path that file should be stored at? Is there a standard path to use for app files? Or do you just randomly store to the SDcard (like some of the examples imply)?